# Form autosubmit on radio/checkbox action (Python Flask)

Tags: jquery, python, forms, flask, submit

I currently am working on a dashboard tool. here I use Python to go through a dataframe, and create filters based on the data. I have the following code as an example output:

```
<form name="FormYear" method="post">
  <div class="panel">
    <div id="checkboxes">
      <div class="filterdiv">
        Forecast Year
        <button class="filterButton clearfilter" type="submit" name="submit" value="clearFilterYear">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="filterButton filter" type="submit" name="submit" value="filter">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <input value = "1" type="hidden" name="FormYear"> 
      <input type="radio" name="Year" id="Year2016" value="2016" checked class="checkbox" >
      <label class="checkboxLabel" for="Year2016">2016</label>  
      <input type="radio" name="Year" id="Year2017" value="2017"  class="checkbox" >
      <label class="checkboxLabel" for="Year2017">2017</label>  
      <input type="radio" name="Year" id="Year2018" value="2018"  class="checkbox" >
      <label class="checkboxLabel" for="Year2018">2018</label> 
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The above code contains 2 submit buttons (one to submit the selections, and one to clear all selections) and 3 radiobuttons. in order to style the radio buttons I am using the Labels and css.

The dashboard will contain many such forms, and I would like to be able to have the form submit whenever the user either checks a checkbox, or a radio button.

Basically I need to have the site hit the second button whenever the user changes a filter.

Can this be done?

Comment: Should be simple with a bit a of JQuery, you can handle the 'change' event on the radio buttons and submit the form via Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Flask-Sijax](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Sijax/), it helps you add [Sijax](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Sijax) support to your Flask applications. Sijax is an easy to use AJAX library.

```
@flask_sijax.route(app, '/hello')
def hello():
   def say_hi(obj_response):
      obj_response.alert('Hi there!')
   if g.sijax.is_sijax_request:
      # Sijax request detected - let Sijax handle it
      g.sijax.register_callback('say_hi', say_hi)
      return g.sijax.process_request()
      return _render_template('sijaxexample.html')
```